# tie breaker condition in Java for tennis game app

Tags: java, android

I am working on android tennis app and now I need to keep conditions for a tie breaker scores in tennis game.

For example, if the set 1 scores are at 6-6, then the tie breaker game starts from 1-1, 2-2, 3-3 and so on.

Or in other ways, How I can implement the tie-breaker rule in tennis game for the below code

I am thinking about how to keep this condition working on my app but not able to get it. I am new to Java, so any help will be appreciated.

/*
        * The method for the Player1 starts below
        * */

```
    assert countBtn1 != null;
    countBtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CountA++;

            textViewScore.setText(CountA+"--"+textViewCount1.getText()+"--"+textViewCount2.getText());

            if (CountA == 1) {
                textViewCount1.setText("15");
            } else if (CountA == 2 ) {
                textViewCount1.setText("30");
            } else if (CountA == 3) {
                textViewCount1.setText("40");
            }

            /*
            * After the game is reached to the level of 40-0 for player 1, it checks all the rules of the tennis before finishing the Game
            * */

            else if (CountA == 4) {
                if (CountB == 3 && textViewCount2.getText().toString().equals("40")  && textViewCount1.getText().toString().equals("40")) {
                    textViewCount1.setText("AD");
                   CountA--;
                }
                if (CountB == 4 && textViewCount2.getText().toString().equals("40") && textViewCount1.getText().toString().equals("40")) {
                    textViewCount1.setText("AD");
                    CountA--;
                }
                if (CountA == 4 && textViewCount1.getText().toString().equals("40") && textViewCount2.getText().toString().equals("15")) {
                    textViewCount1.setText("0");
                    textViewCount2.setText("0");
                    CountA--;
                    if(set1 != 7) {
                        set1 = set1 + 1;
                        textView1.setText("" + set1);
                        CountA=0;
                    }
                }
                if (CountA == 4 && textViewCount1.getText().toString().equals("40") && textViewCount2.getText().toString().equals("30")) {
                    textViewCount1.setText("0");
                    textViewCount2.setText("0");
                    CountA--;
                    if(set1 != 7) {
                        set1 = set1 + 1;
                        textView1.setText("" + set1);
                        CountA=0;
                    }
                }
                else if (CountA == 4 && textViewCount1.getText().toString().equals("AD") && textViewCount2.getText().toString().equals("40")) {
                    textViewCount1.setText("0");
                    textViewCount2.setText("0");
                    CountA--;
                    if(set1 != 7) {
                        set1 = set1 + 1;
                        textView1.setText("" + set1);
                        CountA=0;
                        CountB=0;
                    }
                }
                else if (CountA == 4 && textViewCount1.getText().toString().equals("40") && textViewCount2.getText().toString().equals("AD")) {
                    textViewCount1.setText("40");
                    textViewCount2.setText("40");
                    CountA--;
                }
                else if (CountA == 4 && textViewCount1.getText().toString().equals("40") && textViewCount2.getText().toString().equals("0")) {
                    textViewCount1.setText("0");
                    textViewCount2.setText("0");
                    CountA--;

                    /*
                    * The below functions checks the incrementation clause of the game for the sets
                    * */

                    if((set1 <= 4 && set4 != 6 && set2 == 0 && set5 == 0)
                            || (set1 == 5 && set4 !=7 && set2 == 0 && set5 == 0)
                            || (set1 == 5 && set4 == 6 && set2 == 0 && set5 == 0)
                           // || (set1 == 6 && set4 == 6 && set2 == 0 && set5 == 0)
                            || (set1 == 6 && set4 == 5 && set2 == 0 && set5 == 0))

                    {
                        set1 = set1 + 1;
                       // tie1++;
                       // textViewCount1.setText(""+tie1);
                        textView1.setText("" + set1);
                        CountA=0;
                        if((set1 ==6 && set4 <=4 && set2 == 0 && set5 == 0)|| (set1 ==7 && set4 <= 6 && set2 ==0  && set5 == 0))
                        {
                             builder.setMessage("Player 1 wins the 1st set")
                                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {}
                                    });
                            AlertDialog theAlertDialog = builder.create();
                            theAlertDialog.show();
                        }

                    }

                   else if ( set1 == 6 && set4 == 6 && set2 == 0 && set5 == 0){



                        for (tie1=100; tie1 <= 1; tie1++){
                            textViewCount1.setText("" + tie1);

                            CountA=0;
                        }


                    }

                     else if((set2 <= 5 && set5 != 6 && set3 == 0 && set6 == 0)
                            || (set2 == 5 && set5 != 7 && set3 == 0 && set6 == 0)
                            || (set2 == 6 && set5 == 5 && set3 == 0 && set6 == 0)
                            || (set2 == 6 && set5 == 6 && set3 == 0 && set6 == 0))
                    {
                        set2 = set2 + 1;
                        textView2.setText("" + set2);
                        CountA=0;
                        if((set1 == 6 && set4 <=4 && set2 ==6 && set5 <=4 && set3 == 0 && set6 == 0) || (set2 ==7 && set5 <= 6 && set3 ==0  && set6 == 0))
                        {
                            //builder.setTitle("Game Over");
                            builder.setMessage("Player 1 won the Match by winning both the Sets")
                                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                            CountA = 0;
                                            CountB = 0;
                                            textView1.setText("0");
                                            textView2.setText("0");
                                            textView3.setText("0");
                                            textView4.setText("0");
                                            textView5.setText("0");
                                            textView6.setText("0");
                                            textViewCount1.setText("0");
                                            textViewCount2.setText("0");
                                            set1 = set2 = set3 = set4 = set5 = set6 = 0;
                                        }
                                    });
                            AlertDialog theAlertDialog = builder.create();
                            theAlertDialog.show();
                        }
                        else if((set4 ==6 && set1 <=4 && set2 ==6 && set5 <=4 && set3 == 0 && set6 == 0)|| (set2 ==7 && set5 <= 6 && set3 ==0  && set6 == 0))
                        {
                            builder.setMessage("Player 1 wins the 2nd Set")
                                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


                                        }
                                    });
                            AlertDialog theAlertDialog = builder.create();
                            theAlertDialog.show();

                        }

                    }

                    else if((set3 <= 4 && set6 != 6)
                                    || (set3 == 5 && set6 !=7 )
                                    || (set3 == 5 && set6 == 6 )
                                    || (set3 == 6 && set6 == 6 )
                                    || (set3 == 6 && set6 == 5 ))

                    {
                        set3 = set3 + 1;
                        textView3.setText("" + set3);
                        CountA=0;
                        if((set3 ==6 && set6 <=4) || (set3 ==7 && set6 <= 6 ))
                        {
                            //builder.setTitle("Game Over");
                            builder.setMessage("Player 1 won the Match by winning both the Sets")
                                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                            CountA = 0;
                                            CountB = 0;
                                            textView1.setText("0");
                                            textView2.setText("0");
                                            textView3.setText("0");
                                            textView4.setText("0");
                                            textView5.setText("0");
                                            textView6.setText("0");
                                            textViewCount1.setText("0");
                                            textViewCount2.setText("0");
                                            set1 = set2 = set3 = set4 = set5 = set6 = 0;
                                        }
                                    });
                            AlertDialog theAlertDialog = builder.create();
                            theAlertDialog.show();
                        }

                    }
                    else{
                        CountA = 0;
                    }

                }
                else if (CountA == 5 && textViewCount1.getText().toString().equals("40") && textViewCount2.getText().toString().equals("40")) {
                    textViewCount1.setText("AD");
                    textViewCount2.setText("40");

                }
            }
        }
    }
    );
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish, can you be more specific and provide another example?

Comment: One more example will be, when the tennis game reached tie breaker situation, the scores of the game starts from 1-1, 2-2 instead of normal play of game of 15,30,40..Just want to know how to implement this rule in java using above code

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have a proper implementation of score like 40-0, 15-15 etc. then it should be straightforward to mirror it into a helper method that handles `tiebreak`.

As your code is very verbose I can't tell you how to do it line by line, but simply think of the tiebreak as another additional set and implement it the same way you'd implement a set:

i.e. have a `counterA` and a `counterB` and if player A wins a point increment his counter, otherwise increment counter for B - and as soon as one of the player's counter reaches the number that has him win the `tiebreak` (e.g. condition for A to win would be: **either** `counterA == 6` and `counterA - counterB >= 2` **or** `counterA == 7` (via `if`, `else if`) - that is if I remember tennis rules correctly)

Then only call your `tiebreak` method as soon as the set score has reached 6-6 (however you choose to do this check is fine) and return the winner of the `tiebreak` to the method that handles the set functionality.